# how to apply filters on a posgres JSONField in django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I have a model similar to this:

```py
# segment/models.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField

class Segment(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    # docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield
    data = JSONField('data', 'data')
```

in field ***data*** I store JSON data similar to this

```py
{
    "length": 123.45
    "difficulty": {
        "avg": "easy"
        "max": "advanced"
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to query data as following:

- *api/segments/?data__difficulty__avg=easy*

to filter all records where

- *data.difficulty.avg="easy"*.

to do this, I set up the serializer:

```py
# api/serializers.py
from rest_framework import serializers

class SegmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Segment
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'data']
```

and the view looks like this:

```py
# api/views.py
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend
from .serializers import SegmentSerializer
from segment.models import Segment

class SegmentViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Segment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SegmentSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = ['id', 'name', 'data']
```

when I call

- *api/segments*

I get the following error

```py
AssertionError at /api/segments/
AutoFilterSet resolved field 'data' with 'exact' lookup to an unrecognized field type JSONField. Try adding an override to 'Meta.filter_overrides'. See: https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/ref/filterset.html#customise-filter-generation-with-filter-overrides

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/api/segments/
Django Version: 2.2.7
Python Executable: /Users/udos/.virtualenvs/ts/bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.4
.
.
.
```

I tried adding *data = serializers.JSONField()* to the serializer:

```py
# api/serializers.py
from rest_framework import serializers

class SegmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    data = serializers.JSONField()
    class Meta:
        model = Segment
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'data']
```

but the error persists. so I'm not applying it correctly :|

how is this done properly?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying the same thing and found the [`SearchFilter`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#searchfilter).

So for you, it'd be something like:

```
# api/views.py
from rest_framework import filters
from .serializers import SegmentSerializer
from segment.models import Segment

class SegmentViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Segment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SegmentSerializer
    filterset_fields = ['id', 'name']
    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter]
    search_fields = ['data__difficulty__avg']
```